# How to display the full dates in a month row to column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show the row values as column name in sub query method.

```
location | date
india    | 1-1-2019
india    | 2-1-2019
india    | 3-1-2019
india    | 4-1-2019
india    | 5-1-2019
japan    | 6-1-2019
japan    | 7-1-2019
japan    | 8-1-2019
japan    | 9-1-2019
japan    | 10-1-2019
japan    | 11-1-2019
korea    | 12-1-2019
korea    | 13-1-2019
korea    | 14-1-2019
korea    | 15-1-2019
korea    | 16-1-2019
korea    | 17-1-2019
```

this is the table structure but i need the output like this

```
location | 1-1-2019 | 2-1-2019 | 3-1-2019 | 4-1-2019 | 5-1-2019 | 6-1-2019 | 7-1-2019 | 8-1-2019 | 9-1-2019 | 10-1-2019 | 11-1-2019 | 12-1-2019 | 13-1-2019 | 14-1-2019 | 15-1-2019 | 16-1-2019 | 16-1-2019 |
```

I need this above output. just show the row values of date to column name using sub query or anything

```
Labels    1/1/2019  1/2/2019    1/3/2019    1/4/2019    1/5/2019    1/6/2019    1/7/2019    1/8/2019    1/9/2019    1/10/2019   1/11/2019   1/12/2019   1/13/2019   1/14/2019   1/15/2019   1/16/2019   1/17/2019   1/18/2019   1/19/2019   1/20/2019   1/21/2019   1/22/2019   1/23/2019   1/24/2019   1/25/2019   1/26/2019
china   5   2   2   5   4       7   1   3   3       6               6   3   3   3       3   6   1   1   2   4
india   37  8   8   7   7   23  4       8   4   15  10      4       5   1   5   6   20  4       4   6   12  
japan   6   10  5   10  13      13  11  12  6   7   9       9   10  7   5   10  46      10      14  7   8   
london  17  32  35  36  52  78  35  21  26  27  30  23          81  49  27  38  49      30  21  38  34  34
```

I am using dynamic method to show the date values in column names. But it is not working.

this query is using in this method

```
      select 
    LOCATION
    ,SUM(case when VISIT_DATE='1-1-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as '1-1-2019'
    ,SUM(case when VISIT_DATE='1-2-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as '2-2-2019'
.
.
.
 ,SUM(case when VISIT_DATE='1-31-2019' then 1 else 0 end) as '2-31-2019'
    from 
    testing_table
    where 
    APPOINTMENT_TYPE='REG'
    group by LOCATION
    order by LOCATION
```

Comment: I suspect you'll need Dynamic SQL. What attempts have you have made so far? There are plenty of examples here on SO.

Comment: I think it's not possible, column names should be unique.

Comment: @Sridhar: share your piece of code  and the approaches you have made so that we can see if we can help

Comment: If you need a headstart you can search for the PIVOT function.

Comment: expected output is the row or the column headings only??

Comment: i want date column values should show as column names dynamically using sub query or pivot method anything guys

Comment: Dates as columns headers, any reason why you are structuring your output this way?

Comment: @jimmy8ball i need to do pivot method so am asking

Comment: Using this method would generate you 365 columns at the end of a year period - assuming you are doing some rolling cumulative aggregation. Not the best fit I wouldn't have thought.

Comment: i need to dynamically add the date using while method in stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot and dynamic query to achieve this result. Below query is just a sample to show how Pivot and dynamic query will work together, you can change the query as per your table structure.

```
DECLARE @Pivot_Column [nvarchar](max);  
DECLARE @Query [nvarchar](max);  

/*Select Pivot Column*/  
SELECT @Pivot_Column= COALESCE(@Pivot_Column+',','')+ QUOTENAME(Year) FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT [Year] FROM Employee)Tab  

/*Create Dynamic Query*/  
SELECT @Query='SELECT Name, '+@Pivot_Column+'FROM   
(SELECT Name, [Year] , Sales FROM Employee )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(Sales) FOR [Year] IN ('+@Pivot_Column+')) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY Tab2.Name'  

/*Execute Query*/  
EXEC  sp_executesql  @Query
```